# Scrollbar to Top of iFrame Container Div on Each Page Load?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, scrollbar

I have an iframe with external content that is scrolled from a parent div (the iframe has a large height, while the iframe container div has a smaller height).

As a result, when I scroll to the bottom, the scrollbar stays there when I load another page into the iframe.

Is there any way to send the container scrollbar to the top whenever the iframe loads another page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this was relatively simple, but it wasn't working for me when I had the javascript in an external file. So I put it into the HTML file:

```
<script language="javascript">
function gotop()
{
document.getElementById('iframeContainer').scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>

<iframe src="http://whatever.com" onload="gotop()"></iframe>
```